# Strange behavior with 'bin' and 'optbin'

Tags: r

EDIT: Not sure if this is a question I can make here... I have received a negative valoration 0_o, so let me know if its not proper. I have reelaborated my question.

I'm having problem with OneR::bin and OneR::optbin

While binning, its is creating negative values in lower limit of first range.

```
a <- c(0:10)
b <- OneR::bin(a,nbins=5,method = "content")
summary(b)
(-0.01,2]     (2,4]     (4,6]     (6,8]    (8,10] 
        3         2         2         2         2
```

Same thing happens with 'OneR:optbin'

Do you know if this is a bug, a problem with my computer, or it's a normal behavior of the function? May it be because, as the interval is OPEN on the left, it must use a value BELOW the min? Does it really matters, as it's just a label I can change to [0,2]?

Thanks!

Comment: We need a minimal reproducible example that isolates the problem. Consider using  ```dput() ``` to make any data available.

Comment: Sorry. I have changed my post to show a very simple example.